# Lat / Long return Blanks in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this table which I want to convert In Geometry

```
   ID    Latitude   Longitude
   1     10.7342874 106.6338047
   2     10.0012723 105.090843
   3     10.0012782 105.0908511
   4     10.0035792 105.7513834
   5     10.0037653 105.7518815
   6     10.0043956 105.0868678
```

I am using this query to transform in geometry

```
alter table GPS add geographyColumn as geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),Longitude)+' '+convert(varchar(20),Latitude)+')',4326);
```

It returns me in the preview results like if it was a wrong projection and I can't see the Labels. What is wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why construct a string and force the server to re-parse it when you could just call [`Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: alter table GPS add GEOM as geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude , 4326); I change for this wont make difference still dont have labels...

Comment: @SimonGIS can you show the select statement?

Comment: Select label column
This option is not available when only point instances are returned in a query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/spatial-results-window   . "when only", this is not correct, as labels are not available at all if there is a point column in the result set.

Comment: thanks, @lptr That answer my question